# Using Amiibo for hints, is there a way to skip the text?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey, amiibo

To get hints I always have to go through the text, hit left, place the amiibo and confirm.

https://twitter.com/fredy31/status/926992962789154817

Is there a way to expedite the process? Like skipping the text, or scanning more than one amiibo at once?

Comment: PS: Wanted to put the Switch video from twitter to the site, can't figure how to embed it here or convert it to gif.

Comment: You could upload the video to YouTube then embed it in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to skip that text or bulk scan amiboos.

PS: I'm a completionist, and seeing that question unanswered in my account bugs me. Seeing as nobody had an answer in 3 months and I've not seen any clue there is a way, I'm gonna conclude there is no way.